# What changes is the Neural Network back-propagation algorithm doing on the weights?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, machine-learning, discrete-optimization, neural-networks

I have seen the formula for back-propagation algorithm for neural network error minimization, but I am not quite sure about what changes it is performing on the weights individually.

Let us suppose a simple neural network as follows:

[image]

All the weights between the connection nodes are initialized to 1.

There is no activation function, so dot product of the weights and inputs from the previous level is transmitted unchanged to the next level.

Here, the original inputs are 1 and 1. The final outputs thus becomes 4 in this case. Suppose we would like to change the weights such that the "corrected" output will exactly match the desired target output=1.

[image]

My question is, *what will the resulting weight values be (as in the above diagram) after applying changes prescribed by the back-propagation algorithm?*

Thank you.

Comment: The idea isn't to change the weights to exactly reproduce the desired output - it's to nudge them all to move in the *direction* of the desired output.  Note that all the operations involved are differentiable.

Comment: @user3716267 thank you for answering! yes, i understand that the real training would use a learning rate to slow down the minimization. But in this case, I am just curious to know what will be the new numbers for the weights suppose we want to eliminate all errors immediately using the back-propagation algorithm in one step?

Comment: Start by taking the derivative of the output with respect to the two nodes that feed into it, and see where you can go from there.  Can you figure out from that how each of those could be changed to reproduce the output (note again that this isn't necessarily unique)?  Once you've figured it out for the two immediate nodes before the output, simply repeat your steps as you work backwards through the graph.

Comment: @user3716267 i have seen the formula, but it just doesn't click yet for me... what does the derivative mean as this is just 1 instance of a discrete function. Aren't derivatives defined for analytical functions?

Comment: You can consider the output of the final node given the activations of the two immediately-preceding nodes to be a differentiable function of the weights.  Calculate the derivative with respect to each weight.

Comment: @user3716267 could you help calculate the correct weight correction for one of the weights above, please? I will work backward and try to understand the logic...